# Producer app crashes when Kafka cluster is offline

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

Kafka brokers were restarted and as a result producer application crashed. Messages are being sent to kafka in an async fashion which means if the kafka broker is offline, the producer app should not have any effect since there will be no blocking threads. I wanted to understand why the producer app crashed. Any suggestions?

```java
public void pushMessage(P partitionKey, M message, Consumer<Exception> exceptionHandler) {
   executorService.submit(() -> {
      // this.producer -> KafkaProducer<P, M> from the kafka lib
       producer.send(record, (metadata, exception) -> {
           if (exception != null && exceptionHandler != null) {
               exceptionHandler.accept(exception);
           }
       });
   });
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the async commits wait for Kafka connection to be available. Eventually the producer will run out of retries (assuming you configured it to) and either crash, or drop messages. Without seeing your code, it's hard to know how you handle either case

Comment: @cricket_007 Here is my producer config

ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG = 1
ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG = 1
ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG = none
ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG = 5000 ms
ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG = 5000ms
ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG = 15000ms
ProducerConfig.CONNECTIONS_MAX_IDLE_MS_CONFIG = 15000ms
ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG = 100ms
ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG = 1048576 . 

Do you think there might be some misconfiguration for this producer leading it to crash when cluster is offline?

Comment: I'm not understanding why it would not crash. Are you expecting it to remain up, but just fail sending messages at all? Can you [edit] the post with the full producer logic?

Comment: @cricket_007 Yes, I am expecting the app to remain up and not crash when the kafka cluster is offline. Basically, I want to build a resilient kafka producer which can stay alive even when the kafka cluster completely goes offline. I have updated the post with the producer logic.

Comment: I feel like Akka Alpakka might handle this better since it was built with back pressure in mind. Otherwise, I'm not sure I understand what your `exceptionHandler.accept ` is doing. Plus, it would be useful to show the stacktrace of your application crashing